# ChartJS colored box in axis label

Tags: javascript, chart.js, legend, axis-labels, box

I am trying to create a line chart with ChartJS where the colored boxes, which can normaly be found in the legend are rigth infront of the axis label. Is there any way to create a colored box there or to move the "parts" of the legend independently?
I don't want to have the labels AND the legend...
Any suggestions, help appreciated.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("load");
var loadChart = new Chart(canvas, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["X"],
    "datasets": [{
      "label": "valueLegendY1",
      "fill": "false",
      "borderColor": "#98bbcc",
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(238,59,59,0.0)",
      yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
      "data": []
    }, {
      "label": "valueLegendY2",
      "fill": "false",
      "borderColor": "#d9edf7",
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(238,59,59,0.0)",
      yAxisID: "y-axis-2",
      "data": []
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      },
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'valueLabelY1'
        },
        id: "y-axis-1"
      }, {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'valueLabelY2'
        },
        id: "y-axis-2",
        position: "right",
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'time',
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 30
        }
      }]
    },
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    animation: {
      duration: 0
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        boxWidth: 50,
        fill: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The axis should look somewhat like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyjdf.png)

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind your request. Where do you want to place color boxes exactly? I copied your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/matrixatp/79jqc34n/) and it seems some options are broken. Which labels do you want to add/remove and which colors should be there?

Comment: I fiddled a bit more, it looks like you can only change the text color via `fontColor` option.

Comment: Yes I know the chart itself is not working as the underlying data is taken out of an database. However i want to place legend-like boxes next to the infront of the axis labels.

Comment: Unfortunately those labels are added independently from the datasets as they are just two and the datasets can be many. So the colors wouldn't make sense there. Therefor, you have to manually add them. I didn't find a way to do it other than my previous comment.